# Transformer ou Converter?

Tags: java, design-pattern

Tenho trabalhado em alguns projeto e me deparo com situações onde um determinado objeto tem que ser transformado em outro.

No geral,  são classes java originadas no COBOL que eu converto para um outro tipo, porém com nomes de classes, métodos e atributos mais claros e intuitivos.

Tenho usado o [Apache Collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/), mais especificamente a interface [Transformer](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/Transformer.html) e classes utilitárias relacionados.

Tenho adotado como nome da classe algo como `<NomeDoBean>Transformer`. Minha pergunta é:

**Qual a diferença entre `Converter` e `Transformer`, nesse contexto?**

Sei que [JSF usa o termo `Converter`](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/j2ee101302/jsf_apps/eventvalidate/sf_avc_converters.html). **Qual termo usar e por que?**